# How do i stop pop up window while clicking arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a pop-up window while clicking that green arrow. Then, when it's clicked again, hide that pop-up window.. I wrote the coding below but it's hide suddenly.. How do I fix it.. using only javascript not jquery..

`My fiddle:`
http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/213/

Please anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

You have to target `onclick` for `arrow-down`, not `rightone li ul`

Try this code:

### JS

```
var log1 = document.querySelector('.arrow-down');
var log2 = document.querySelector('.rightone li ul');

log1.onclick = function() {
var display = getComputedStyle(log2).getPropertyValue("display");
if ( display !== "block" ) {
    log2.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    log2.style.display = 'none';
}
};
```

### CSS

```
.rightone, .arrow-down, .rightone li ul{float:right;}
.rightone ul 
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.rightone ul li 
{
display: block;
position: relative;
}
.rightone li ul 
{
display: none;
}
.rightone ul li a 
{
 display: block;
padding: 2px 30px ;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.rightone ul li li 
{
background-color:pink;
border-radius:2px;
padding: 2%;  
}
.rightone ul li a:hover 
{
color:#0ef2c4;
}

.rightone li ul 
{
 padding-top:20px;
}
.rightone li:hover a
{
 color:black;
}
.rightone li:hover li a:hover 
{
 color:#0ef2c4;
 }
 .arrow-down {
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
border-right: 8px solid transparent;
border-top: 8px solid #0ef2c4;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right:50px;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t5Nf8/215/